# Cycles Planet - Trouble with Atmosphere

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I've been trying to add some kind of atmosphere to a planet I'm making with Cycles in Blender for a few hours now and every time, I get the same problem. The atmosphere goes beyond the boundary where the sun (Light) I'm using goes. I'm also trying to figure this out without using the shadow terminator. Thank you for your help!
Here are a few images : Planet Render, Atmosphere Material and Full Scene. [image: Planet Render]

[image: Atmosphere Material]

[image: Full Scene]

Comment: In reality, the atmosphere would be a different sphere than the surface of the planet. Try one with no shaders for the surface and  volume scattering and some volume absorption.

Comment: Try using the search box at the top of the page for similar questions. This topic has been asked and answered many times over: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=atmosphere and https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=planet+atmosphere and https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=planet+volume

Comment: Related : https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/92327/29586